# I can't print character in C using printf

Tags: c, char, printf, cs50

I am trying to print the output of the function "char rotate(char c, int n)" but it will print only the numbers and not the characters. any help is appreciate it.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


bool only_digits(string arg);
char rotate(char c, int n);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

   // Make sure program was run with just one command-line argument

   if (argc !=2)

    {
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return 1;
    };

    // Make sure every character in argv[1] is a digit
    if ( only_digits(argv[1])==0)
    {
     printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
     return 1;
    };

     // Convert argv[1] from a `string` to an `int`
     int key = atoi(argv[1]);

    // Prompt user for plaintext//
    string text = get_string("plaintext: \n");

    // For each character in the plaintext:

     printf("ciphertext: ");

     for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
     {
      char ch = (rotate(text[i], key));
      
      printf("%c", ch);
     };


}

bool only_digits(string arg)
{
      // Rotate the character if it's a letter
     for (int i = 0; i < strlen(arg); i++)
     {
         if (!isdigit(arg[i]))
         {
          return false;
         }
     }
     return true;
}

char rotate(char c, int n){

     if (isupper(c))
     {
          c -=65;
          c = (c + n) % 26;
          c = c + '0';
          return c;
     }

      else if (islower(c))
     {
          c -=97;
          c = (c + n) % 26;
          c = c + '0';
          return c;

     }
      else
      return c;


}
```

I tried different ways of casting the integers into characters and experimenting with a debugger and using printf statement to figure out what's causing this to no avail.

Edit1:
in my original post I deleted bunch of my code thinking it's not relevant to my issue but some of the questions asked about those parts, so hopefully now it's more clear.
when I type abc it print no thing at all, just "plaintext: "

Comment: Why does the code "add back" the character `'0'` after it has "rotated" an upper or lower case letter? Think about this operation carefully.

Comment: why subtract 65 then add '0'?

Comment: Please use `strtol` instead of `atoi`

Comment: If `c` starts as `'N'`, this `c = (c + n) % 26;` sets `c` to `13` + some offset modulo 26.  Just what `char` do you think something like `'0' + 13` results in?

Comment: You cannot safely use `argv[1]` until AFTER you've checked that `argc >= 2`...

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: Wadah, Try entering in `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`.  Does it print with a line-feed someplace?  Review `c = c + '0';` and explain why code adds a `'0';`.

Comment: I did this as I read somewhere this is way to cast integers into characters

Comment: OT: (after OP posts edit) While the code in the functions appears alright, the code in `main()` has unnecessary `;` after closing curly brackets. While this is innocuous in this instance, it would be illegal were there to be an `else` clause after an `if`... Just FYI...

Comment: @Wadah Adding a value to `'0'` is not "casting". Regardless, try changing the `'0'` to `'A'` in the uppercase instance and `'0'` to `'a'` in the lowercase instance...

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP eventually determined a major issue.

Code was substring a `'0'` when an `'A'` or `'a'` should have been subtracted.

---

To handle other issues:

**`is...(ch)` has trouble when `ch < 0`**

Best to use `unsigned char`.

**Avoid magic numbers like 65**

**Avoid negatives and overflow errors**

`c + n` may overflow

The sum may be negative.  So let us work with certain positive numbers.

**Unneeded `else`**

---

```
// In main(), bring `key` into the range [0...25];
int key = atoi(argv[1]);
key &= 26;  // key now in the [-25 ... 25] range
if (key < 0) key += 26; 

// n is in the 0...25 range.
static char rotate(char c, int n) {
  unsigned char uch = (unsigned char) c;
  if (isupper(uch))  {
    uch = (uch - 'A' + n) % 26;
    return uch + 'a';
  }
  if (islower(uch))  {
    uch = (uch - 'a' + n) % 26;
    return uch + 'a';
  }
  return c;
}
```

Comment: 26 is also sort of magic, replace with `('z' - 'a' + 1)`.

Comment: @n.m. Maybe.  Rather than code `('z' - 'a' + 1)` in many places, better as `#defined ALPHABET_SIZE ('z' - 'a' + 1)`  and use `ALPHABET_SIZE` or the like.  As for the learner OP, just taking things a few steps at a time.